# Flashing procedure not able to open port

Tags: esp32, esp-idf, espressif-idf

Trying to build LVGL port to ESP32 demo project and flash to `WT32-SC01 PLUS With 3.5 inch 320X480` module with `ESP32-S3-WROVER` chip. Build was done with ESP-IDF v4.4.4 version without problems. But flashing command  `idf.py -p 9 flash` generates error:

```
Executing action: flash
Running ninja in directory c:\cpp_test\!esp32\lv_port_esp32\build
Executing "ninja flash"...
[1/5] cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\cpp_test\!esp32\lv_port_esp32\b....bin C:/cpp_test/!esp32/lv_port_esp32/build/lvgl-demo.bin"
lvgl-demo.bin binary size 0x67210 bytes. Smallest app partition is 0x100000 bytes. 0x98df0 bytes (60%) free.
[2/5] Performing build step for 'bootloader'
[1/1] cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\cpp_test\!esp32\lv_port_esp32\build\bootloader\esp-idf\esptool_py && C:\Espressif\python_env\idf4.4_py3.11_env\Scripts\python.exe C:/espressif/frameworks/esp-idf-v4.4.4/components/partition_table/check_sizes.py --offset 0x8000 bootloader 0x1000 C:/cpp_test/!esp32/lv_port_esp32/build/bootloader/bootloader.bin"
Bootloader binary size 0x63b0 bytes. 0xc50 bytes (11%) free.
[2/3] cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\espressif\frameworks\esp-idf-v4...sp-idf-v4.4.4/components/esptool_py/run_serial_tool.cmake"
esptool.py esp32 -p 9 -b 460800 --before=default_reset --after=hard_reset write_flash --flash_mode dio --flash_freq 40m --flash_size 2MB 0x1000 bootloader/bootloader.bin 0x10000 lvgl-demo.bin 0x8000 partition_table/partition-table.bin
Traceback (most recent call last):
esptool.py v3.3.2
Serial port 9
  File "C:\espressif\frameworks\esp-idf-v4.4.4\components\esptool_py\esptool\esptool.py", line 5482, in <module>
    _main()
  File "C:\espressif\frameworks\esp-idf-v4.4.4\components\esptool_py\esptool\esptool.py", line 5475, in _main
    main()
  File "C:\espressif\frameworks\esp-idf-v4.4.4\components\esptool_py\esptool\esptool.py", line 4782, in main
    esp = esp or get_default_connected_device(ser_list, port=args.port, connect_attempts=args.connect_attempts,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\espressif\frameworks\esp-idf-v4.4.4\components\esptool_py\esptool\esptool.py", line 115, in get_default_connected_device
    _esp = chip_class(each_port, initial_baud, trace)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\espressif\frameworks\esp-idf-v4.4.4\components\esptool_py\esptool\esptool.py", line 345, in __init__
    self._port = serial.serial_for_url(port)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Espressif\python_env\idf4.4_py3.11_env\Lib\site-packages\serial\__init__.py", line 90, in serial_for_url
    instance.open()
  File "C:\Espressif\python_env\idf4.4_py3.11_env\Lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 64, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: {!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port '9': FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.', None, 2)
CMake Error at run_serial_tool.cmake:56 (message):
  C:/Espressif/python_env/idf4.4_py3.11_env/Scripts/python.exe
  C:/espressif/frameworks/esp-idf-v4.4.4/components/esptool_py/esptool/esptool.py
  --chip esp32 failed


FAILED: CMakeFiles/flash C:/cpp_test/!esp32/lv_port_esp32/build/CMakeFiles/flash
cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\espressif\frameworks\esp-idf-v4.4.4\components\esptool_py && C:\espressif\tools\cmake\3.23.1\bin\cmake.exe -D IDF_PATH="C:/espressif/frameworks/esp-idf-v4.4.4" -D SERIAL_TOOL="C:/Espressif/python_env/idf4.4_py3.11_env/Scripts/python.exe C:/espressif/frameworks/esp-idf-v4.4.4/components/esptool_py/esptool/esptool.py --chip esp32" -D SERIAL_TOOL_ARGS="--before=default_reset --after=hard_reset write_flash @flash_args" -D WORKING_DIRECTORY="C:/cpp_test/!esp32/lv_port_esp32/build" -P C:/espressif/frameworks/esp-idf-v4.4.4/components/esptool_py/run_serial_tool.cmake"
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
ninja failed with exit code 1
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: If you are using windows (tha's what I assume), have you tried to use 'COM9' instead of just '9'?

Comment: Did you set the target by `idf.py set-target esp32s2`? Otherwise the default esp32 is assumed.

Comment: the same effect with COM9

Comment: I did mistake, actually it is esp32s3 and not esp32s2. But `idf.py set-target esp32s3` has no impact on error